# Retrieving data from SharePoint 2010 list in .Net Core 3.0 Web API

Tags: .net, sharepoint, .net-core, sharepoint-2010, .net-core-3.0

I have recently made the move to using .Net Core rather than .Net Framework. The company I am at requires the use of SharePoint lists.

We use SharePoint 2010. At first I tried using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll file we used for the .Net Framework. As it did not work with .Net Core, I downloaded the Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package from NuGet.

Here is my code that retrieves the list (it works in .Net Framework but not .Net Code)

```
            var customerRegions = new List<CustomerRegion>();

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://workflowsdev/operations/CustomerManagement");
            var SPList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Customer Regions");

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            ListItemCollection entries = SPList.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(entries);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem currentEntry in entries)
            {
                var currentRegion = new CustomerRegion();
                currentRegion.Region = currentEntry["Region"].ToString();
            }

            return customerRegions;
```

The code fails at `context.ExecuteQuery();`

Error:

> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work with .Net Core 3.1? I can not find any solutions online to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently .netcore does not support csom. You can not find a .NET Core Compatible in NuGet package. In the meanwhile there is a UserVoice idea you could vote for:
[Support .NET Core with CSOM](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom)